# Compare n with n+1 in nested array and check if n+1 is within range of 500 from n

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

this is my first question on StackOverflow so I might not include some important info. I need your help with understanding how to reflect the following task in code.

I am setting up a chart and I need to display price points on the chart. The issue is that I do not want to show all the prices on the chart. I want to show only a price if it is outside of range from the previous element of the nested array.

So what I need to do in steps is:

1. Set up a range around elements of an arry. The range should be -500 [n] +500.
2. Compare values from an array. Compare n with n+1, n+2, n+3 etc. to see if n+2, n+3 n+4 etc is within range of 500 units from n.
3. If it is within range, do not add that value to the array. If it is outside of the range 500, then add that value to the final array AND update the price item by moving the RANGE METER now to the next element.Then repeat the loop.

The data that I am passing to the chart is:

```js
var dataForChart = [ 
  { "id": 1111, "data": [
    {"x": "11.04.2019", "y": 25000}, 
    {"x": "11.05.2019", "y": 25200}, 
    {"x": "15.06.2019", "y": 28000}, 
    {"x": "19.07.2019", "y": 30000} ] 
  } , 
  { "id": 2222, "data": [
    {"x": "11.04.2019", "y": 1}, 
    {"x": "11.05.2019", "y": 501}, 
    {"x": "15.06.2019", "y": 550}, 
    {"x": "19.07.2019", "y": 2000} ] 
  }, 
  { "id": 3333, "data": [
    {"x": "11.04.2019", "y": 1000}, 
    {"x": "11.05.2019", "y": 1200}, 
    {"x": "15.06.2019", "y": 1600}, 
    {"x": "19.07.2019", "y": 1700} ] 
  } ]
```

So to use the above data.

If dataForCharts[0].data[0].y is within range 500 from dataForCharts[0].data[1].y, go on with the loop. Once you find dataForCharts[0].data[2].y which is 28000, so outside of range 500 from 25000, then add that price to the final array(to be displayed on the chart), AND now move the RANGE METER to 28000 price point. From now on, count 500 from 28000. So dataForCharts[0].data[3].y = 30000 would be also pushed to the final array.

Move on to the next ID so dataForCharts[1].data[0].y and set the RANGE METER to the dataForCharts[1].data[0].y so start from 1 and not from 28000.

The expected result should be filtered nested arrays of "data":

```js
var dataForChart = [ 
  { "id": 1111, "data": [
    {"x": 11.04.2019, "y": 25000}, 
    {"x": 15.06.2019, "y": 28000}, 
    {"x": 19.07.2019, "y": 30000} ] 
  } , 
  { "id": 2222, "data": [
    {"x": 11.04.2019, "y": 1}, 
    {"x": 15.06.2019, "y": 550}, 
    {"x": 19.07.2019, "y": 2000} ] 
  }, 
  { "id": 3333, "data": [
    {"x": 11.04.2019, "y": 1000}, 
    {"x": 15.06.2019, "y": 1600}] 
  } ]
```

What I thought of is to create a function for the RANGE METER that will check if -500 < n < +500. I think I will will also need to push values to the array. To access the nested array I would use map, which creates a new array. I was trying to implement _.inRange for this task but I am not able to incorporate it in a meaningful manner for this task. Your help would be much appreciated.

I hope I explained what I am trying to achive clearly. Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a smaller problem and gradually build up to the solution you're looking for.

Given a list of numbers `[n, n+1, n+2, n+3]`, only keep the `n+ith` element if it falls outside some interval of the `nth` element.

For example given

```js
const listOfNumbers = [25000, 25200, 28000, 27600, 30000];
```

and assuming an interval of +- 500, we expect an output of

```js
[25000, 28000, 30000]
```

Expanding on your idea of pushing elements into an array, we can do something like this:

```js
/**
 * @param list is a list of values
 * @param isInteresting is a function comparing two values and returning whether
 *                      those values are interesting
 */
const keepInterestingValues = (list, isInteresting) => {
  const [first, ...rest] = list; // split the list into the first element 
                                 // and the rest of the elements
  const answer = [first];        // seed the answer with the first element

  let previouslyInteresting = first;
  rest.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (isInteresting(value, previouslyInteresting)) {
      answer.push(value); // add the number to the list if it's interesting
      previouslyInteresting = value; // update the previously interesting value
    }
  }); 

  return answer;
};
```

We can then define our `isInteresting` function to return true when the two numbers fall outside some interval:

```js
const areNumbersInteresting = (current, prev) => Math.abs(current - prev) > 500;
```

We can now test it out:

```js
const interestingValues = keepInterestingValues(listOfNumbers, areNumbersInteresting);
// => [25000, 28000, 30000]
```

The problem with this solution is that it only works with a list of numbers. Let's up the complexity by updating our solution to work with a list of objects.

```js
const listOfObjects = [
  {"x": "11.04.2019", "y": 25000}, 
  {"x": "11.05.2019", "y": 25200}, 
  {"x": "15.06.2019", "y": 28000}, 
  {"x": "15.07.2019", "y": 27600},
  {"x": "19.07.2019", "y": 30000}
];
```

One interesting thing to note is that our `keepInterestingValues` function can remain the same. We'll need to update our `isInteresting` argument to account for objects though:

```js
const areObjectsInteresting = (x, y) => {
  const current = x.y;
  const prev = y.y;
  return Math.abs(current - prev) > 500; 
};
```

And now we can handle a list of objects:

```js
const moreInterestingValues = keepInterestingValues(listOfObjects, areObjectsInteresting);
// => [
//      { x: "11.04.2019", y: 25000 }, 
//      { x: "15.06.2019", y: 28000 }, 
//      { x: "19.07.2019", y: 30000 }
//    ]
```

The final step as you mentioned is to map over the data for chart

```js
const interestingDataForChart = dataForChart.map(value => {
  return {
    ...value,
    data: keepInterestingValues(value.data, areObjectsInteresting),
  }
})
```

And you'll have the result you're looking for.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this explanation. The way you did it is mindblowing for me. Very clear explanation and good comments. I want to be able in the future, to help people like you did help me! Thank you once again for the time you spent on helping me. Cheers

Comment: No problem, you were definitely on the right track -- just needed to connect the pieces together.